# Xamarin MVVMCross Spinner Show Name in Object

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to take my list of participants and show the participant name in the spinner.

Participant Object:

```
public class Participant
{
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private List _participantFilterList = null;
public List ParticipantFilterList 
{
   get { return _participantFilterList; }
   set {
      _participantFilterList = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => ParticipantFilterList);
   }
}

private Participant _selectedParticipantFilter = null;
public Participant SelectedParticipantFilter
{
    get { return _selectedParticipantFilter; }
    set {
        _selectedParticipantFilter = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedParticipantFilter);
    }
}
```

View:

```
var respondentSelect = fragView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.respondentSelect);
... 
set.Bind(respondentSelect).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.ParticipantFilterList);
set.Bind(respondentSelect).For(x => x.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedParticipantFilter);
```

All of that seems to mostly work by showing me this in the spinner:
[image]

I need it to show me the Participants Name though and I am not sure what I am missing to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a declaration like `MvxItemTemplate="@layout/ParticipantItemTemplate"` in your axml layout file where you bind the actual spinner. Also make sure you declare your spinner as an `MvxSpinner` view.